# AutoCompleteBox bind to web service

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

First time working on silverlight, want to bind AutoCompleteBox(via web service) with image thumb and image title, will search through image title, i'm able to do bind image title

working process

1. Web service

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public List<imagedata> Searchimage(string s)
   {
       var db = new PetaPoco.Database("sales");
       var list = from search in db.Query<imagedata>("select * from   imagedata").ToList() where search.imgname.Contains(s) select search;

       return list.ToList<imagedata>() ;
   }
   ```
2. xaml

   ```
       <sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="searchText"
                 Populating="searchText_Populating" />
               </StackPanel>
   ```
3. .cs

   ```
    private void searchText_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
   {
       mySoapClient proxy = new mySoapClient();

       proxy.SearchimageCompleted +=
                            new EventHandler<SearchimageCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_ImageGetCompleted);
       proxy.SearchimageAsync(searchText.Text);
   }
   void proxy_ImageGetCompleted(object sender, SearchimageCompletedEventArgs e)
   {

       var  searchResults = new List<imagedata>(e.Result);
       var data = new List<string>();

       foreach (var x in searchResults)
       {
           data.Add(x.imgname);
       }
       searchText.ItemsSource = data;

       searchText.PopulateComplete(); 

   }
   ```

Want to bind both image url for image thumb and image title, i apply following process

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="searchText"  Populating="searchText_Populating">
                <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image x:Name="image1" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"></Image>
                    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
```

How can i bind a collection to datatemplate of autocompletebox , Can i use dictionary for this ? if yes then how i bind it to data template

Answer (score 0):

The [ItemsControl documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) should give you almost everything you need to get started.

In your case, you will eventually use Binding syntax to set the ImageSource of the Image in your ItemTemplate. For this to work, you will need to use a value converter to turn your string into something the Image can use.

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="searchText"  Populating="searchText_Populating">
     <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
         <local:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter" />
     </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
...
<Image x:Name="image1" 
       Height="100" 
       Width="100" 
       Canvas.Left="0" 
       Canvas.Top="0"
       ImageSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}">
</Image>
...
```

And the converter:

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string source = value as string;
        if (source != null)
        {
            return new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage 
            { 
                UriSource = new Uri(source, UriKind.Absolute) 
            };
        }

        return source;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```